# Mortal Kombat: Why is Scorpion called that name?

Tags: names, mortal-kombat

One of the most iconic characters of the Mortal Kombat franchise is Scorpion, an undead ninja whose real name is Hanzo Hasashi. He first appeared in the original video game as the arch-enemy of Sub-Zero (the latter name is natural as Bi-Han has the special power of creating ice).

My question is why he was named "Scorpion"?

In the animated movie: "Mortal Kombat Legends: Scorpion's Revenge" there is an answer: In the opening scene we see Hanzo Hasashi's son, Satoshi, watching a scorpion fighting hordes of ants, and Hanzo tells his son that the moral of this is to never give up. Later, when Hanzo resurrected in the Netherealm and demands Quan Chi's for answer, he adopts the name "Scorpion".

However, this movie is relatively new (2021), and I don't know if it is canon. Is there a canon reason (or meta-franchise reason) why is he called Scorpion?

Comment: Mortal Kombat: Legacy - *"His skills with the kunai earned his the nickname "The Scorpion".*

Comment: "Scorpion" narrowly beat out "Sweet Little Bunny" in the match of a grueling 64 nickname bracket elimination.

Comment: His weaponry and [attire](https://www.google.com/search?q=scorpion&tbm=isch&&sclient=img) are Scorpion-themed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how reliable this is, but [Giant Bomb](https://www.giantbomb.com/scorpion/3005-1/) has this to say about Scorpion:

> Scorpion was originally known as Hanzo Hasashi, the greatest warrior
> in the Shirai Ryu ninja clan, though he was already called Scorpion by
> his clansmen out of respect for his assassination skills.

[The Fandom Wiki](https://mortalkombat.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion/Current_Timeline) has this to say:

> Mortal Kombat (2011): "Hanzo Hasashi was once a member of the Japanese
> Shirai Ryu ninja clan. Given the name Scorpion for his blindingly fast
> and deadly fighting skill,

So if these sources are to be believed, his in-universe name was given by his clansmen for his fight skills.

Answer (score 3):

In *Mortal Kombat 4* (1997) he literally turns into a scorpion to perform his fatality move.

---

That being said, his trademark move from the earliest games is his chain-linked [kunai](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/mkwikia/images/d/d9/Scorpion-Mortal-Kombat.png/revision/latest?cb=20110502235720), which clearly resembles the stinger of a scorpion.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's *that* clear its supposed to be a scorpion

Comment: [Toasty!](https://mortalkombat.fandom.com/wiki/Toasty!)